# Is there a way to pass truststore.jks value in place for file location

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, kubernetes, base64, truststore

I connect by Elasticsearch Instance through Spark code .. which requires to pass truststore file location and keystore file location, while instantiating the spark session as below.

```
  .config("es.net.ssl.keystore.location", truststore_location)
  .config("es.net.ssl.keystore.pass", truststore_password)
  .config("es.net.ssl.truststore.location", truststore_location)
  .config("es.net.ssl.truststore.pass", truststore_password)
```

I do have a file location but the challenge here is the value in the truststore.jks file is basically the encoded value of original value. This was done to when the ask was to copy the truststore.jks content and upload it as secret in Kubernetes pod.
I extracted the same by passing

> cat truststore.jks | base64

Now as the file location when passed to spark session builder it gives invalid format error which is obvious. So is there any way by which I can extract the value and decode it and then pass the value ... not any location.
below is the way I loaded the volumes and volume mount for same

```
volumes:
  - name: elasticsearch-truststore
    secret:
      secretName: "env-elasticsearch-truststore"
      items:
        - key: truststore.jks
          path: truststore.jks
volumeMounts:
  - name: elasticsearch-truststore
    mountPath: /etc/encrypted
```

If anyone can suggest any other way I can approach the issue it will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the `secret` object you've created. The `encoded` value is only relevant when the object exists as a manifest in the `etcd` database of `Kubernetes API` server. The encoding has no effect on the actual contents of the secret.

I think what could have caused this is you encoded the contents and then created a secret of the *encoded contents*, which is what you're observing here.

A simple fix would be to delete the existing secret and create a new secret simply from your `truststore.jks` file, as follows:

```
kubectl create secret env-elasticsearch-truststore --from-file=truststore.jks=/path/to/truststore
```

This will create a secret named `env-elasticsearch-truststore` and this will contain one key `truststore.jks` with a value of `/path/to/truststore` file contents.

You can then use this secret as a file by mounting it in your pod, the specification will look like this:

```
...
  volumes:
  - name: elasticsearch-truststore
    secret:
      secretName: env-elasticsearch-truststore
  volumeMounts:
  - name: elasticsearch-truststore
    mountPath: "/etc/encrypted"
...
```

This will ensure that the file `truststore.jks` will be available at the path `/etc/encrypted/truststore.jks` and will contain the contents of the original `truststore.jks` file.

Comment: I agree with you regarding the solution but unfortunately I don't have authorization to run kubectl create and kubectl apply command. So was looking for a solution otherwise. to run the create and apply command have to reach out to a different team